# .htaccess 301 redirect : Migrating site from Zen cart to PS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have created a website in PS and I want to 301 redirect some of the products from an old zen cart site for SEO purposes.

I am pasting this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /store/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/product/465$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mynewdomain/store/mynewproduct.html [R=301]
```

And this file is in the olddomain.com/store/ directory

I have tried modifying the sintaxis, but I haven't managed to make it work! Can someone explain me what is wrong and how can i fix it.

THANKS A LOT

Comment: What is old URL that you want to redirect?

Comment: http://otisjaxonsilverjewellery.co.uk/store/product/465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule as **very first rule** in `/store/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /store/

RewriteRule ^product/465/?$ http://mynewdomain/store/mynewproduct.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: ohh no, it was the position! I was adding the rule at the very end!!! I've tried yours at the end and didn't work, then I mooved it to the beginning and it worked! Thanks a lot